# Arrangement counting problem

Tags: combinatorics

This is my son's exercise: How many ways that 6 rabbits can be put in 10 cages.

I count in 2 different ways:

- The first rabbit can be in any of 10 cages. Same for the second and so on. So in total, there will be $10^6$ ways.
- On the other hand, I list all possible cases:

  1. 6 rabbits in the same cage: there are $C^6_6*10=10$ ways of doing so.
  2. 5 rabbits in the same cage, the other one in a different cage. There will be: $C^6_5*10*9=540$ ways. ($6=5+1$)
  3. 4 rabbits in the same cage, the other 2 in a different cage. There will be $C^6_4*10*9=1350$ ways. ($6=4+2$)
  4. 4 rabbits in the same cage, 1 in different cage, 1 in another different cage. There will be $C^6_4*10*9*8=10800$ ways. ($6=4+1+1$)
  5. 3 rabbits in the same cage, 1 in different cage, 1 in another different cage and 1 in other cage. There will be $C^6_3*10*9*8*7=100800$ ways. ($6=3+1+1+1$)
  6. 3 rabbits in the same cage, 2 in different cage, 1 in another different cage. There will be $C^6_3*10*C^3_2*9*8=43200$ ways. ($6=3+2+1$)
  7. 3 rabbits in the same cage, 3 in different cage. There will be $C^6_3*10*9=1800$ ways. ($6=3+3$)
  8. 2 rabbits in the same cage, 2 in different cage and 2 in another different cage. There will be $C^6_2*10*C^4_2*9*8=64800 $ ways ($6=2+2+2$)
  9. 2 rabbits in the same cage, 2 in different cage, 1 in another different cage and 1 in other cage. There will be $C^6_2*10*C^4_2*9*8*7=453600$ ways. ($6=2+2+1+1$)
  10. 2 rabbits in the same cage, each of the other 4 is in different cage. There will be $C^6_2*10*9*8*7*6=453600$ ways ($6=2+1+1+1+1$)
  11. 6 rabbits in 6 different cages. There will be $C^{10}_6*6!=151200$ ways

In total, there will be $1,281,700$ ways which doesn't match with the first calculation.

Could anyone explain to me why?

Comment: In your case by case count, have you handled symmetries correctly?  Take case #7, for example.  Putting rabbits (A,B,C) in cage #1 and (D,E,F) in #2 is the same as putting (D,E,F) in #2 and then putting (A,B,C) in #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errors are in your cases 7 (as pointed out by lulu), 8 and 9.

- A correct calculation for 7 (the pattern $3+3+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0$) would be $\dfrac{6!}{3!^2 \; 0!^8} \times \dfrac{10!}{2! \; 8!} = 900$ arrangements
- A correct calculation for 8 (the pattern $2+2+2+0+0+0+0+0+0+0$) would be $\dfrac{6!}{2!^3 \; 0!^7} \times \dfrac{10!}{3! \; 7!} = 10800$  arrangements
- A correct calculation for 9 (the pattern $2+2+1+1+0+0+0+0+0+0$) would be $\dfrac{6!}{2!^2 \; 1!^2\; 0!^6} \times \dfrac{10!}{2! \; 2! \; 6!} = 226800$  arrangements

Add these to your other results and you will get $1$ million.